# Save Port number for ember-cli in a config file

Tags: ember-cli

I'm sure I remember seeing some documentation somewhere that had a way to save the port number ember-cli uses in a config file, but it doesn't seem to say anything in the documentation.

I have to use

```
ember server --port 9999
```

but i would love to save that port number in a file.

Comment: I use an alias, easier to do and remember.

Comment: Again that's harder to share with your team. I'm looking to simplify the process so that there are as few barriers for the team adopting this as possible

Comment: And also we currently have about 3-4 different ember apps (hence why we need different ports) so having an alias doesn't work here

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a .ember-cli config file to change the port. [discussion](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/563)

So in your root folder, have a .ember-cli file with the following:

```
{
  "port": 9999
}
```

Edit: the .ember-cli file is now documented on the [ember-cli website](http://www.ember-cli.com/#runtime-configuration).

Comment: Although, it seems to be broken in the latest version. https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1080

Comment: update: The fix has been merged into master, so should be in v0.0.41 if you don't want to deal with #latest

Answer (score 3):

Using a `.ember-cli` file is the way to go according to the ember-cli docs [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments).

I'm using [nitrous.io](http://nitrous.io) - which is fantastic - however it doesn't allow port 4200 - and in any case I wanted the server to be on 3000.

Also, I noticed that the server was starting up and refreshing very slowly - issue seems to be with the live-reload-server - and again the default port.

So, my `.ember-cli` config file now looks like this...

```
{
    "port": 3000,
    "live-reload-port": 4000
}
```

Everything seems ok with nitrous.io and most importantly my server load time is now what you would expect - also, live-reload works great.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `live-reload-port`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the proper place to change it, but changing *node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/serve.js*

```
{ name: 'port', type: Number, default: 4200 },
```

to

```
{ name: 'port', type: Number, default: 9999 },
```

seems to do it.

Comment: The problem with that one is that whenever you update ember-cli it will override it, and you can't share that config with your team to make sure it is proxies by nginx correctly etc.